# Asm, why the first code slower than second code while 1st use less instruction?

Tags: assembly

First Code:

```
    .file   "CountChar.cpp"
    .text
    .align 2
    .globl  _ZN2JQ7cString9CountCharEPKc
    .type   _ZN2JQ7cString9CountCharEPKc, @function
_ZN2JQ7cString9CountCharEPKc:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
#APP
# 21 "CountChar.cpp" 1
    movq %rdi,%rbx
    testq %rbx,%rbx
    jne .JQcStringCountChar1Start
    movq $-1,%rax
    jmp .JQcStringCountChar1End
    .JQcStringCountChar1Start:xor %rdx,%rdx
    .JQcStringCountChar1Lo0:mov (%rbx),%cl
    test %cl,%cl
    jne .JQcStringCountChar1Lo1
    mov %rdx,%rax
    jmp .JQcStringCountChar1End
    .JQcStringCountChar1Lo1:js .JQcStringCountChar1Lo2
    inc %rbx
    jmp .JQcStringCountChar1LoEnd
    .JQcStringCountChar1Lo2:movzbw %cl,%ax
    and $224,%ax
    cmp $192,%ax
    jne .JQcStringCountChar1Lo3
    add $2,%rbx
    jmp .JQcStringCountChar1LoEnd
    .JQcStringCountChar1Lo3:movzbw (%rbx),%ax
    and $240,%ax
    cmp $224,%ax
    jne .JQcStringCountChar1Lo4
    add $3,%rbx
    jmp .JQcStringCountChar1LoEnd
    .JQcStringCountChar1Lo4:movzbw (%rbx),%ax
    and $248,%ax
    cmp $240,%ax
    jne .JQcStringCountChar1Lo5
    add $4,%rbx
    jmp .JQcStringCountChar1LoEnd
    .JQcStringCountChar1Lo5:movzbw (%rbx),%ax
    and $252,%ax
    cmp $248,%ax
    jne .JQcStringCountChar1Lo6
    add $5,%rbx
    jmp .JQcStringCountChar1LoEnd
    .JQcStringCountChar1Lo6:movzbw (%rbx),%ax
    and $254,%ax
    cmp $252,%ax
    jne .JQcStringCountChar1LoError
    add $6,%rbx
    jmp .JQcStringCountChar1LoEnd
    .JQcStringCountChar1LoError:mov $-2,%rax
    jmp .JQcStringCountChar1End
    .JQcStringCountChar1LoEnd:inc %rdx
    jmp .JQcStringCountChar1Lo0
    .JQcStringCountChar1End:
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   _ZN2JQ7cString9CountCharEPKc, .-_ZN2JQ7cString9CountCharEPKc
    .ident  "GCC: (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.5, pie-0.6.4) 4.9.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

execute 10000000 times:

```
real    0m6.293s
user    0m6.196s
sys 0m0.005s
```

2nd Code

```
    .file   "CountChar.cpp"
        .text
        .align 2
        .globl  _ZN2JQ7cString9CountCharEPKc
        .type   _ZN2JQ7cString9CountCharEPKc, @function
    _ZN2JQ7cString9CountCharEPKc:
    .LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        pushq   %r12
        pushq   %rbx
        .cfi_offset 12, -24
        .cfi_offset 3, -32
        movq    %rdi, %rax
        testq   %rax, %rax
        jne .L2
        movq    $-1, %rax
        jmp .L3
    .L2:
        movq    %rax, %rbx
        movl    $0, %r12d
        jmp .L4
    .L11:
        movzbl  (%rbx), %eax
        testb   %al, %al
        js  .L5
        addq    $1, %rbx
        jmp .L6
    .L5:
        movzbl  (%rbx), %eax
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        andl    $224, %eax
        cmpl    $192, %eax
        jne .L7
        addq    $2, %rbx
        jmp .L6
    .L7:
        movzbl  (%rbx), %eax
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        andl    $240, %eax
        cmpl    $224, %eax
        jne .L8
        addq    $3, %rbx
        jmp .L6
    .L8:
        movzbl  (%rbx), %eax
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        andl    $248, %eax
        cmpl    $240, %eax
        jne .L9
        addq    $4, %rbx
        jmp .L6
    .L9:
        movzbl  (%rbx), %eax
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        andl    $252, %eax
        cmpl    $248, %eax
        jne .L10
        addq    $5, %rbx
        jmp .L6
    .L10:
        movzbl  (%rbx), %eax
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        andl    $254, %eax
        cmpl    $252, %eax
        jne .L6
        addq    $6, %rbx
    .L6:
        addq    $1, %r12
    .L4:
        movzbl  (%rbx), %eax
        testb   %al, %al
        jne .L11
        movq    %r12, %rax
    .L3:
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %r12
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
    .LFE0:
        .size   _ZN2JQ7cString9CountCharEPKc, .-_ZN2JQ7cString9CountCharEPKc
        .ident  "GCC: (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.5, pie-0.6.4) 4.9.3"
        .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

execute 10000000 times:

```
real    0m5.326s
user    0m5.176s
sys 0m0.002s
```

Comment: less instruction doesn't mean faster execution, because they may loop more times, or use more inefficient instructions, or use different flow/algorithm... And at least learn [how to format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) first. I've edited for you once and you continue to mess the post

Comment: Part of the problem here could also be the accuracy of your measurements, are you running on top of an operating system?  Instruction count is of course note a good indicator for performance as has been stated...

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the details: *instruction count is not a good measurement*.

Each instruction has a potential different amount of CPU cycles it uses, so simply counting instructions is not good enough; it is like counting cars in a parking lot to get their total price.

Answer (score 0):

CPU's stopped being simple a long time ago.
Counting the number of instructions is a totally meaningless metric.
You need to take into account that the fact that modern CPU's are [superscalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor) and execute [Out of Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution) (OoO).
Also, you need to know the [number of cycles that an instruction typically](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) takes.
A much better metric is the length of the [longest dependency chain and the number of instructions that the CPU can execute in parallel](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf).

Take the following piece of code for instance:

```
mov eax,1      //1 cycle
@loop:
inc eax        //1 cycle, does not update CF
adc ecx,ebx    //2 cycles + 1 cycle because of partial register write in EFLAGS
imul ecx,ebx   //3 cycles
```

This code takes 8 cycles, all of which are waiting on one another, because they form one long dependency chain.

The following code

```
mov eax,1             //1 cycle
xor edx,edx           //0 cycles, pairs
@loop:
setc dl               //1 cycle edx = carry
add ecx,ebx           //0 cycles, pairs
lea eax,[eax+1]       //0 cycles, pairs, does not alter flags
lea ecx,[ecx+edx]     //1 cycle
imul ecx,ebx          //3 cycles
```

This code takes 6 cycles, even though it's more instructions.
It's a silly example and the breaking up of `ADC` into `setc + add` does not help us. Even though it's more instructions it still runs faster because I've broken up the dependency chain a bit and used instructions that do not alter the flags.